# Adding horizontal scroll bar forcefully

Tags: html, css

I an using joomla, in my page I want to add horizontal scroll bar I am getting vertical scroll bar properly. this is my web Page screen shot

[image]
the inside portion is coming as iframe

I want to put horizontal scroll forcefully

Comment: `overflow-x: scroll;`

Comment: element's width is not exceeding the width, that's why you are not getting...use overflow:scroll; in css. / overflow-x:scroll;

Answer (score 4):

You have to add the css

`body {overflow-x: scroll;}`

or overflow-y for the element that you want to give the scroll bar to.

Comment: I tried that but it is not working 
http://198.46.84.72/~demo/inter/index.php?option=com_wrapper&view=wrapper&Itemid=185&lang=en

Comment: I tested on firebug on your demo. According to it your screen.css has on the beginning overflow-x:hidden; for body & html. Change that to overflow-x: scroll or overflow-x:auto if you want it to be shown only when needed and you should be good to go. 

If for some reason your change has no effect it might be you made it on a css-file that was loaded before screen.css and thus overriden. If you can't access screen.css you can add 'overflow-x:scroll !important;'

Answer (score 0):

In your code screen.css, line no. 1; `overflow-x:hidden.`

Make

```
overflow-x:scroll;
```